# Should these dependencies be removed?

Tags: java, gradle, hadoop

I have a spring boot application and want to clean my project. Firstly I started clean  to  unused dependencies. I used **nebula lint** plugin to detect unused dependency. Mostly I cleaned many dependencies but I doubt I should clean the following dependencies.

When I removed to these dependencies, my application did successfully complete build stage and I don't take any error in runtime. But I doubt for following dependencies. Should I remove the following dependencies?

**Output 1 :**

```
warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is a service provider unused at compileClasspath time and can be moved to the runtimeOnly configuration (no auto-fix available)
 
implementation(group: "org.apache.hadoop", name: "hadoop-yarn-common", version: 3.3.0) 

warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is unused and can be removed
implementation(group: "org.apache.hadoop", name: "hadoop-yarn-common", version: 3.3.0 )
```

**Output 2 :**

```
warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is a service provider unused at compileClasspath time and can be moved to the runtimeOnly configuration (no auto-fix available) 
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core', version: 3.3.0) 

warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is unused and can be removed
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core', version: 3.3.0)
```

**Output 3 :**

```
warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is a service provider unused at compileClasspath time and can be moved to the runtimeOnly configuration (no auto-fix available)
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient', version: 3.3.0) 


warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is unused and can be removed
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient', version: 3.3.0)
```

**Output 4 :**

```
warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is a service provider unused at compileClasspath time and can be moved to the runtimeOnly configuration (no auto-fix available)
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-common', version: 3.3.0)

warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is unused and can be removed
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-common', version: 3.3.0)
```

**Output 5 :**

```
warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is a service provider unused at compileClasspath time and can be moved to the runtimeOnly configuration (no auto-fix available)
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-yarn-server-common', version: 3.3.0)

warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency is unused and can be removed
implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-yarn-server-common', version: 3.3.0)
```

Comment: So if you remove them, your code builds and works perfectly? Then yes: you should remove them. What other criteria do you expect?

Comment: Now I am running in local and I don't take any error. But once when I deployed to remote server, I took error in run time.Error's resource was log4j slf4j loop.I excluded the slf4j and problem solved(It ran perfectly on local,I took error in remote server).I don't know very well big data technologies(Hadoop, Hive,Yarn...)Maybe It will take error in future(maybe another server will send data and It will take error ) and additionally nebula lint doesn't say directly unused-dependency firstly it says you can move because server provider etc. then it says unused-dependency.So I doubt unfortunately